# How set Http setHeader?

Tags: java, android, response

I use below code:

```
class Test extends AsyncTask < String, Void, String > {

 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String...urls) {
  String response = "";
  for (String url: urls) {
   DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
   try {

    HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
    InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
     new InputStreamReader(content));
    String s = "";
    while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
     response += s;
    }

   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
  return response;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
  TestLogin.textView.setText(result);

 }

}
```

What changes should be modified in above code to set header?
I want to get access to my webpage jsonObjcets "http://apimobile.dev2.rtbtracker.com/api/v2/users"

Comment: `DefaultHttpClient` has been deprecated now. Avoid using it!

Answer (score 0):

You can set headers on the `httpGet` object.

See the [documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/message/AbstractHttpMessage.html?is-external=true#setHeader(org.apache.http.Header)) for `setHeader` before `client.execute(httpGet)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setHeader()` method on the `HttpGet`

```
httpGet.setHeader("Header-Name", "Header Value");
```

**In your code :**

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

//Setting the header
httpGet.setHeader("Header-Name", "Header Value");

try {

   HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);

   //process

} catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
httpGet.addHeader('headerName', 'headerValue'); // will work
```

This line adds the header to the HttpGet Object which goes to the request url when you run HttpClient.execute()

Comment: Code only answer are not recommended, please add some information on why this code would work - From Review

Answer (score 0):

```
response.setHeader("name", "value");
```